# React-select-fast-filter-options does not work properly

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use [React Virtualized Select](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select) combined with [react-select-fast-filter-options](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-select-fast-filter-options)

*react-virtualized-select* works well for me, but somehow I can not get *react-select-fast-filter-options* to work after following all steps in Git guide, after entering some value to select input, I got no results at all.

I ve created codesnippet in Code Sandbox for this issue https://codesandbox.io/s/v34qnr9w0
It does **not** work if *labelKey* is *content*, but when you change *labelKey* to *label*(default value), it works again.

The following is the complete code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Select from 'react-virtualized-select';
import createFilterOptions from 'react-select-fast-filter-options';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
import 'react-virtualized-select/styles.css'

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const options = [
      { id: 'Stanford University', content: 'Stanford' },
      { id: 'Stan University', content: 'Stan' },
      { id: 'Stanford BBB University', content: 'Stanford BBB' },
      { id: 'Stanford CCC University', content: 'Stanford CCC' }
    ];

    const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({ options });

    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <Select
          name="university"
          labelKey="content"
          valueKey="id"
          options={options}
          filterOptions={filterOptions}
          onChange={val => console.log(val)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is a component' bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing your non-default `labelKey` property to `react-virtualized-select` but *not* passing it to `react-select-fast-filter-options` (which is what's actually indexing your data). This second library accepts a `labelKey` param; (check out [the params documentation](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-select-fast-filter-options#configuration-options)).

So the fix is to do this:

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  labelKey: 'content',
  options
});
```

By the way, CodeSandbox is having a caching problem at the moment so [I moved your example to WebpackBin and fixed it there](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KxEWOirLTPfVuHaf-JZ).

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @bvaughn Where can I see all the default properties that `react-viratualized-select` has? (As you say `labelKey` property is non-default, I want a list of all the default properties that I don't need to pass to `react-select-fast-filter-options`).

Comment: @LavishKothari Did you look at the params documentation my answer specifically linked to? It very clearly shows which keys have default values.

Comment: Ah, I missed it. Thanks for explicitly pointing it out. It's [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-select-fast-filter-options#configuration-options).